# How can I get a $var from a config file to display in my template?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to pull in vars from a config file to display in a template. Below are my files related..

index.php

```
<?php
//Setting up important stuff
require_once('class/template.class.php');
define('INCLUDES_PATH', 'includes');
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.'/config.php');
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.'/css.php');
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.'/js.php');
define('TEMPLATES_PATH', 'templates');
define('PARTIALS_PATH', TEMPLATES_PATH.'/partials');

//Instanciate new object
$template = new Template(TEMPLATES_PATH.'/index.tpl.php');


//Assign values
$template->assign('title', 'Home');

$template->assign('content', '<?php echo $script; ?> TEST');

$template->assign('footer', 'This is my Footer');


//Use a Partial
$template->renderPartial('table_here', PARTIALS_PATH.'/table.part.html', array('username' => 'Blood_Wolf89', 'age' => 25));

//Showing content
$template->show(true);

?>
```

template.class.php

```
<?php

class Template {

    private $assignedValues = array();
    private $partialBuffer  = '';
    private $tpl            = '';


    function __construct($_path = ''){

        if(!empty($_path)){

            if(file_exists($_path)){

                $this->tpl = file_get_contents($_path);

            }else{

                echo "<b>Template Error:</b> Base File Inclusion Error. <b>File: '$_path'</b><br />";

            }

        }

    }

    function assign($_searchString, $_replaceString = ''){

        if(!empty($_searchString)){

            $this->assignedValues[strtoupper($_searchString)] = $_replaceString;

        }


    }

    function renderPartial($_searchString, $_path, $_assignedValues = array()){

        if(!empty($_searchString)){

            if(file_exists($_path)){

                $this->partialBuffer = file_get_contents($_path);

                if(count($_assignedValues) > 0){
                    foreach ($_assignedValues as $key => $value){

                        $this->partialBuffer = str_replace('{'.strtoupper($key).'}', $value, $this->partialBuffer);

                    }

                }

                $this->tpl = str_replace('['.strtoupper($_searchString).']', $this->partialBuffer, $this->tpl);
                $this->partialBuffer = '';

            }else{
                echo "<b>Template Error:</b> Partial Inclusion Error. <b>File: '$_path'</b><br />";
            }

        }

    }

    function show($debug = false){

        if(count($this->assignedValues) > 0){

            foreach ($this->assignedValues as $key => $value){

                $this->tpl = str_ireplace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->tpl);

            }

        }

        if($debug){

            $this->tpl .= '<!--'.date('d-m-Y H:i:s').'-->';

        }
        echo $this->tpl;
    }

}





?>
```

index.tpl.php

```
<?php include '../includes/config.php'; ?>
```

{TITLE}

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

```
<!-- START NAV -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li  class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- END NAV -->



<div class="container">
  <h2>{CONTENT}</h2>

</div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <p class="text-muted">{FOOTER}</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

config.php

```
<?php

// Script Info
$script     = 'BASE';
$version    = '0.0.1 Dev.';

?>
```

I have googled it and I cant seem to search the correct terms. I know it is out there but I just need to find it. Sorry and thanks in advance!

Comment: Use $template->assign function to pass value of variable in template file.

Comment: Should I just put that kind of info directly in the template.class.php instead of in the config?

Comment: Better yet, Do you have a short example of how you would do so? Thanks, Blood

Comment: I got it to work, Thank you! I will post what I did to help others if they have the same issue and come across this thread.

Comment: IS THIS SMARTI Template?

Comment: No, Its hand made. No Templates..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I created a function in the template.class.php

```
function added (){
        echo $script;


    }
```

In the index.php I called it like so..

```
$template->assign('content', ''. $script.' TEST');
```

Thanks to Vijay Verma